# TortoiseSvn error : the same name as the administrative directory

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am working with TortoiseSVN. I've performed a checkout to an empty folder. Some files get transferred but then, at some point I receive the following error:

*Error: Failed to add directory 'D:\code\Website\ClientBin_svn': object of

Error: the same name as the administrative directory*

I tried deleting the folder and checking out the project to a different directory. It doesn't work. When I try to check out the project on a different computer on a different lan it works fine. Any ideas?

Thanks,
vondiplo

Answer (score 6):

You have a file or folder named "_svn" or ".svn" in your repository. This is a bad idea because your subversion client already uses one of those as a reserved name for storing meta-data inside your local working copies.

Open the repository browser, locate the evil file or folder in the repository, and delete (or rename) it.

Comment: Or rename it, if it contains content you want to keep.

Answer (score 1):

See if you have configured TortoiseSVN to use `_svn` instead of `.svn`.

This is a per installation configuration options, and can thus be different from one computer to the next.

Right-click in a folder, open the TortoiseSVN menu, and select Settings. The tab named "General", at the bottom, should have that checkbox.

Now, I don't think it is that checkbox, since you say the name is "ClientBin_svn", but that was the first thing that hit me.

The administrative directory of Subversion is the hidden .svn directory that gets created containing the svn working copy data.