# svn checkout fail due to a folder named .svn in my tree

Tags: git, svn, version-control

My question is similar but different from this one:
[TortoiseSvn error : the same name as the administrative directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923375/tortoisesvn-error-the-same-name-as-the-administrative-directory)

I use `git-svn` as client and I had a test data which contains a fake `.svn` folder in the data tree. This got `dcommitt'ed` to svn. Now when I try to checkout a fresh working copy using `svn co`, I got error:

```
svn: E155000: Failed to add directory '/MyRepo/TestData/Root/.svn': object of the same name as the administrative directory
```

I've tried to delete that folder and dcommitt'ed again. But it didn't help.

**UPDATE**

I figured something out.

I was on a feature branch where I removed the `.svn` folder (only one file under) using:

```
git rm /MyRepo/TestData/Root/.svn/file
git commit
```

Then I switched back to my development branch, merged the feature branch in, and finally checked in:

```
git checkout develop
git merge --squash feature
git commit
git svn dcommit
```

I'm surprised that this, however, didn't merge in the .svn removal change.
I double checked my `~/.gitignore`, `~/.gitignore_global`, repo's `.gitignore`. They didn't include `.svn`, actually that should be irrelevant since my checkin worked for `.svn` folder all the time.

Can someone explain what happened here???

**UPDATE 2**

Seems that re-checking in the `git rm` change from my development branch still doesn't solve the issue. `svn co` still fails at the same place with the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the cause and the solution.

The git change had to be the removal of the file `.svn/file`. git automatically removes the .svn folder from the local git repo. But folders are a first-class citizen in svn. so The .svn folder didn't get removed when doing `git svn dcommit`.

I ended up having to do

```
svn del http://mysvnserver/MyRepo/TestData/Root/.svn -m "Remove .svn folder"
```

to remove that folder separately. After that I can `svn co` normally.

Problem solved.